# How to get IP address of hostname inside jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

Our saltstack is based on hostnames (webN.*, dbN.*, etc.). But for various things I need IPs of those servers. For now I had them stored in pillars, but the number of places I need to sync grows.

I tried to use publish + network.ip_addrs, but that kinda sucks, because it needs to do the whole salt-roundtrip just to resolve a hostname. Also it's dependent on the minions responding. Therefore I'm looking for a **way to resolve hostname to IP in templates**.

I assume that I could write a module for it somehow, but my python skills are very limited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a custom grain. Create file _grains/fqdn_ip.py in the state tree directory:

```
import socket

def fqdn_ip():
    return {
        'fqdn_ip': socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
    }
```

In template:

```
{{ grains.fqdn_ip }}
```

Another way is use dnsutil module (requires dig command on minion):

```
{{ salt['dnsutil.A']('host.name.tld')[0] }}
```

Comment: That would return the ip of the machine the salt is running on, right? That's not exactly what I need. I need to resolve arbitary hostnames like `{{ host2ip(pillar.db.hostname) }}`.

Comment: I add another way to the answer.

Comment: Also, you can create [macros](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.jinja.html#macros) host2ip

Comment: In the end I used my copy-paste-fu with a grain of common-dev-sense and created a module, that uses `socket.gethostbyname`, which works like I need - problem with dnsutil would be it does not respect `/etc/hosts` which I need.

Comment: `socket.gethostbyname` _may_ be vulnerable to being exploited using [GHOST](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2015/01/29/the-ghost-vulnerability-what-you-need-to-know/). It would be advisable to use `socket.getaddrinfo` which is not vulnerable and works for IPv4 and IPv6

Answer (score 5):

I've see this: 
http://cnygaard.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/how-to-template-eth0-address-with.html

This is the easy way that I've found.

```
#init.sls:

...
...

/etc/swift/proxy-server.conf:              
   file:
     - managed                              
     - source: salt://swift/proxy-server.conf
     - template: jinja
     - context:
         proxy_ip: {{ salt['network.interfaces']()['eth0']['inet'][0]['address'] }}
```

And then:

```
#In proxy-server.conf

...

[filter:cache]
use = egg:swift#memcache
memcache_servers = {{ proxy_ip }}:11211
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old post, but it is highly ranked in Google for getting the ipv4 address.  As of salt **2015.5.8**, the best way to get the primary ipv4 address is `{{ grains['ipv4'][0] }}`.

Comment: Could you please explain more thoroughly what you mean by {{ grains['ipv4'][0] }} ?

Comment: That it's first entry in the ipv4 key in grains (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/grains.html) - obviously, you can access it any way you want ;)

Comment: In salt, grains is an array of values (or hashmap or similar).  Using the 'ipv4' grain, you can access all IPv4 addresses on the minion.  For my purpose, I need the primary IPv4 address or the 0th entry.

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the ansible documentation, I found a much simpler solution. Here are my results.

enter the following into the template:

```
lookup hostname: {{ lookup('dig', 'google.ca.') }}
```

My jinja2 template:

```
# mytemplate.j2
## lookup directly
lookup hostname: {{ lookup('dig', 'google.ca.') }}

## in a variable
{% set fqdn = 'google.ca' %}
lookup hostname: {{ lookup('dig', fqdn) }}
```

Result:

```
# mytemplate.j2
## lookup directly
lookup hostname: 172.217.2.163

## in a variable
lookup hostname: 172.217.2.163
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently - to aggregate a list of all ip addresses requires either salt-mine or interrogating all minions.  I prefer salt-mine.

There is an accepted issue to extend the new roster system to maintain addresses of all minions, not just ssh based hosts.  https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/7759

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder, you always can pass it from Flask app.

```
import os

host = os.uname()[1]

return render_template("template.html", host=host)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get IPs that are not available in grains, do not want to setup custom grains and need those IPs to be dynamically resolved in your pillars ( typically to setup the firewall, network interfaces, BGP to the host, etc. ) you can proceed as follow:

Let's say you have:

- idrac-hostname.domain
- management-hostname.domain
- hostname.domain

Then you can just resolv them using the dig modules from SaltStack

```
{% set fqdn = salt['grains.get']('fqdn') %}
{% set idrac = 'idrac-' ~ fqdn %}

{% set idrac_ip = salt['dig.A'](idrac)[0] %}
{% set main_ip = salt['dig.A'](fqdn)[0] %}
```

Hope it helps

Ref: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.dig.html